# What is the word for two objects that one comes after another one

Tags: word-request

For example, suppose that in a queue two objects are next  <s>after</s>  **to** each other, what is the word to describe them

two succeeding objects?

Comment: two thing next after each other ? is it a circle or my English is terrible ?

Comment: "two things, *one* after *the* other"

Comment: _Successive_ might work for you, although it doesn't always mean only two.   (Three successive attempts to climb Mt. Everest failed.  In two successive years, I spent more money on repairing my car than I was able to save.  If you win too may successive hands in Vegas, they may ask you to leave the casino.)  _Consecutive_ works about the same way.

Comment: Difference between successive and consecutive:  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5790/whats-the-difference-between-successive-and-consecutive

Comment: **Subsequent**: Coming after something in time; following. TBH though, I don't really understand the question.

Comment: @JoeDark They are objects not events, I modified the question.

Comment: Sequential?  Consecutive?  Neighboring?  Adjacent?  Following?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things in a queue, such that one thing follows the other, are called "***adjacent***".  We also describe them as "*next to each other*".

They can't be "*after each other*", either *one is after the other* or vice versa, the *other is after the one*, if the queue has a direction, that is.

Comment: Thanks, but your answer lacks the main question, as one suggested "successive".

Comment: Sure. Once you know one answer, others come easy, don't they?  Hind sight and all that...  Just use a thesaurus.